# CSS Toggle Accordion Acting Strange, Thoughts?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hey so the toggle switches only work correct after you click, meaning on page load the switches are all 'minus' when it should only be the collapsed one, then when you click, the closed tabs work appropriately.. please help!

```css
.panel-default {
  border-color: #fff!important;
}

.panel-title {
  font-size: 24px!important;
}

.accordion-toggle a:hover {
  text-decoration: none!important font-color:#2ad4ff!important;
}

.panel-default>.panel-heading+.panel-collapse>.panel-body {
  border-top-color: #ddd;
  text-align: left!important;
}

.panel-default>.panel-heading {
  color: #333;
  background-color: #fff!important;
  border-color: #fff!important;
  text-align: left!important;
  border-width: 0px!important;
}

.panel-heading .accordion-toggle.collapsed:after {
  float: left!important;
  color: #000!important;
  margin-right: 20px;
  font-size: 30px!important;
  LINE-HEIGHT: 30PX!important;
}

.panel {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 0px solid transparent;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px!important;
}

.panel-heading .accordion-toggle:after {
  float: left!important;
  color: #000!important;
  margin-right: 20px;
  font-size: 30px!important;
  LINE-HEIGHT: 30PX!important;
}

.panel-heading .accordion-toggle:after {
  /* symbol for "opening" panels */
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  /* essential for enabling glyphicon */
  content: "\2212";
  /* adjust as needed, taken from bootstrap.css */
  float: right;
  /* adjust as needed */
  color: grey;
  /* adjust as needed */
}

.panel-heading .accordion-toggle.collapsed:after {
  /* symbol for "collapsed" panels */
  content: "\2b";
  /* adjust as needed, taken from bootstrap.css */
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container-toggle">
  <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
          Collapsible Group Item #1
        </a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
        <div class="panel-body">
          Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
          on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table,
          raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo">
          Collapsible Group Item #2
        </a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">
          Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
          on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table,
          raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree">
          Collapsible Group Item #3
        </a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">
          Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
          on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table,
          raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed your code adding `collapsed` class to your collapsed anchor tags like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified Bootstrap CSS -->

    <div class="container-toggle">
      <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
              <a
                class="accordion-toggle"
                data-toggle="collapse"
                data-parent="#accordion"
                href="#collapseOne"
              >
                Collapsible Group Item #1
              </a>
            </h4>
          </div>
          <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
            <div class="panel-body">
              Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life
              accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non
              cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt
              laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
              on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et.
              Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred
              nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice
              lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim
              aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them
              accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
              <a
                class="accordion-toggle collapsed"
                data-toggle="collapse"
                data-parent="#accordion"
                href="#collapseTwo"
              >
                Collapsible Group Item #2
              </a>
            </h4>
          </div>
          <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">
              Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life
              accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non
              cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt
              laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
              on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et.
              Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred
              nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice
              lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim
              aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them
              accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
              <a
                class="accordion-toggle collapsed"
                data-toggle="collapse"
                data-parent="#accordion"
                href="#collapseThree"
              >
                Collapsible Group Item #3
              </a>
            </h4>
          </div>
          <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">
              Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life
              accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non
              cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt
              laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
              on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et.
              Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred
              nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice
              lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim
              aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them
              accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- end container -->

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

the CSS remains the same.

This is because the + sign is added when the anchors have the collapsed class.

Here you have a [CodePen](https://codepen.io/richard-fazzi/pen/qBBvQWB) to test it.

Comment: Incredible and fast too, thank you so much I really really appreciate it Richard!

Comment: my pleasure, hope it helps you! Regards

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the classes 'in' (on the panel) and 'collapsed' (on the title link) and how they toggle on click.  If you want to default certain panels to open or closed in the way you currently has set up, you'll need to have them start with those classes added in the HTML as appropriate - otherwise the styles associated with 'collapsed' aren't getting applied until click because that's when the class is first added.

Comment: Code will be very useful here :)

Comment: @JoshNuzzi you're welcome - best of luck on your project!